# Switch on/off Yii debug toolbar dynamically

Tags: debugging, yii, yii2, toolbar

Is it possible to switch on/off Yii2 debug toolbar dynamically, for example if request url contains "debug=1" or "debug=0"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The debug toolbar is provided 
by Debug Extension for Yii 2    https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-debug/blob/master/docs/guide/README.md

The activation of this toolbar is related to the presence of these constant in your `app/web/index.php`

```
defined('YII_DEBUG') or define('YII_DEBUG', true);
defined('YII_ENV') or define('YII_ENV', 'dev');
```

Do the fact these value are in constant this should implies that cannot be changed runtime ..

so  the activation/deactivation of the toolbar  is possible offline only.

Or at least it implies the change of these constants in the entry point of the application file that is in the file index.php. You can try to change it dynamically rewriting the code (it's dangerous .but it should be possible)

Answer (score 2):

In addition to [scaisEdge](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3522312/scaisedge) answer, you could do it as a client-side technique. In other words, using [css](/questions/tagged/css). However, you should **notice** that solution is just hiding the debug toolbar contents not preventing them to be generated.

The debug toolbar contents are rendered in a `div` with `id` attribute value `yii-debug-toolbar`. In your main layout, you may do something like the following:

```
<?php $this->endBody() ?><!- after this line -->
<?php if (Yii::$app->request->get('debug') == '0'):?>
<style>
  #yii-debug-toolbar{
    display: none !important;
  }
</style>
<?php endif; ?>
</body>
```

### Update

To maintain a way to dynamically show/hide the debug toolbar from the server-side, not only from the client side as regarded in my original answer, you will have to play with the entry script `web/index.php` using a property of the debug module class named [**`allowedIPs`**](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-debug-module.html#$allowedIPs-detail) in which we will set an impossible IP number when `debug` URL parameter equals to `0`:

```
?php

// comment out the following two lines when deployed to production
defined('YII_DEBUG') or define('YII_DEBUG', true);
defined('YII_ENV') or define('YII_ENV', 'dev');

require(__DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php');
require(__DIR__ . '/../vendor/yiisoft/yii2/Yii.php');

/* The solution */
$config = require(__DIR__ . '/../config/web.php');
if (isset($_GET['debug']) && $_GET['debug'] == '0'){
  $config['modules']['debug']['allowedIPs'] = ['1270.05.0.1'];
}


(new yii\web\Application($config))->run();
```

Comment: Really not a good idea, except if you want to give all this data to hackers

Comment: In development phase, you may need to have a quick way to hide the debug toolbar from the presentation, like viewing end design or something like that. This is may be good way in this aspect. @soju

Comment: In other words, suppose that the designer said, "Hi dev, please hide that damn toolbar!" :) You just have to tell him to visit the page with an URL parameter `debug=0`